# Can the SHA-256 hash be derived from the SHA-512hash of the same data?

Tags: security, hash, sha

I am applying SHA-512 on data. Is it theoretically/practically possible to derive the SHA-256 hash for the original data from its SHA-512 hash?

Comment: Which way round are you actually interested in? The title says 256 to 512; the text says 512 to 256.

Comment: Your title says "512 from 256"; your question body says "256 from 512".  Which is it?!

Comment: Do you mean finding some function F so that SHA256(n) == F(SHA512(n)) ?

Comment: @GregS: Clearly it's impossible to get the 512 from the 256 (due to pigeonhole principle).  Is it really a clear-cut "no" the other way round?

Comment: What this really boils down to is, for all inputs `x` and `y` such that `SHA512(x) == SHA512(y)`, is it the case that `SHA256(x) == SHA256(y)`?  All we need is a single counter-example...

Comment: Every 2^256th pair should have this property. But there are no known collisions in either of those hash-functions. But of course they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they have different number of rounds, different size of internal state and different block-size I'm pretty sure that the result of SHA-256 and SHA-512 are so different that you can't derive either of them from the other.

But if you are paranoid you could append/prepend different data for the different hash-functions. i.e. you calculate `SHA-256("A"+data+"B")` and `SHA-512("D"+data+"E")` (of course with longer strings instead of ABCD).

The only possibility I see is if the set of possible input values is small that you brute-force possible values until you hit the known hash and then calculate the other hash. Basically if the conditions are so that the attacker can reverse the known hash, he can also calculate the other hash.

Comment: You may not be able to derive it with some closed-form expression, but there is still the *theoretical* possibility of simply using an enormous lookup table.

Comment: I don't see how a lookup table could be useful here. IMO attempting to guess the input is the only viable attack apart from pretty much completely breaking the cryptography happening inside the hashes.

Comment: I agree.  You cannot derive a SHA-256 knowing only the SHA-512 because the algorithms operate on different size blocks and run for a different number of rounds.  A SHA-256 hash isn't just a "short" version of a SHA-512 hash.  This is the nature (and usefulness) of cryptographic hash functions.

Comment: In *theory* a large enough lookup table would solve pretty much any problem... now how long will it take to build such a table and how large would it be?  I'm thinking about 10^142 TB for a full SHA-512 table, right?  Haha... maybe we strayed a bit here from feasibility.

Comment: @MDaubs Even that table wouldn't solve the problem. Since you get only one input that matches a given SHA512 hash. And not necessarily the one that was originally hashed. And thus you still can't calculate the SHA-256 hash of the original data.

Comment: `SHA-256("A"+data+"B")` doesn't satisfy the paranoid. Just use [HMACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Cryptographers generally agree that `"A"+data+"B"` is in the realm of "we don't have any attacks for this, but we are going to assume one exists." -1